# How to increment in vim under windows (where CTRL-A does not work...)

Tags: vim

While <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> works fine in vim under windows, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> selects all (duh).

Is there a way to increment a number with a keystroke under windows?

Comment: If you don't want the select all behavior, I think you can do `:nunmap <C-A>` to go back to the default increment behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Ctrl-NumPad + ?

([from here](https://web.archive.org/web/20080912200928/http://www.vim.org/tips/tip.php?tip_id=305))

Comment: thanks. just to complete the answer, one need to also:
:noremap <C-kPlus> <C-A>

Comment: Link is dead now. Just a friendly reminder, I know this answer is almost 3 years old :)

Comment: And when you don't have a NumPad?

Comment: You can `:noremap <C-A> <C-A>` in your vimrc

Answer (score 9):

You can make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to increment in windows by opening up the 'mswin.vim' file in your vim directory and finding the section that looks like:

```
" CTRL-A is Select all
noremap <C-A> gggH<C-O>G
inoremap <C-A> <C-O>gg<C-O>gH<C-O>G
cnoremap <C-A> <C-C>gggH<C-O>G
onoremap <C-A> <C-C>gggH<C-O>G
snoremap <C-A> <C-C>gggH<C-O>G
xnoremap <C-A> <C-C>ggVG
```

Comment out all of these lines as follows:

```
" CTRL-A is Select all
"noremap <C-A> gggH<C-O>G
"inoremap <C-A> <C-O>gg<C-O>gH<C-O>G
"cnoremap <C-A> <C-C>gggH<C-O>G
"onoremap <C-A> <C-C>gggH<C-O>G
"snoremap <C-A> <C-C>gggH<C-O>G
"xnoremap <C-A> <C-C>ggVG
```

and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> keystroke will increment.

This is a pretty nice option when your keyboard doesn't have a real number pad.

Comment: Being a primary Linux user, this helped me to use the same control

Answer (score 5):

I realize that this is an old question, but I ran across another option today based on the following question. Making gvim act like it does on linux will allow CTRL-A to work as you expect it to:

[how to make gvim on windows behave exacly like linux console vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093578/how-to-make-gvim-on-windows-behave-exacly-like-linux-console-vim)

There is a section of the _vimrc that has the following items. These cause many of the control characters to act like they do on Windows.

```
set nocompatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin
```

I commented out (with `"`) the mswin lines and the `set nocompatible` line. From there, I added `set compatible`. This causes gvim to act like it does on linux. Thus, mine looks something like:

```
set compatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
"set nocompatible
"source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
"behave mswin
```

I just learned this trick today, so if I'm not completely correct in my information, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

I modified TMealy's solution so that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> still selects all (I find this useful), while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> increments (also useful).

```
noremap <C-I> <C-A>

" CTRL-A is Select all
noremap <C-A> gggH<C-O>G
inoremap <C-A> <C-O>gg<C-O>gH<C-O>G
cnoremap <C-A> <C-C>gggH<C-O>G
onoremap <C-A> <C-C>gggH<C-O>G
snoremap <C-A> <C-C>gggH<C-O>G
xnoremap <C-A> <C-C>ggVG
```

Comment: but Ctrl-I is for jumping to newer cursor position.

Answer (score 2):

A similar problem occurs under GNU/Linux when using Vim with [`mswin.vim`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_w32.html#gui-clipboard).
Remapping <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> prior to evoking `mswin.vim` solved my issue.

```
execute "set <A-x>=\ex"
noremap <A-x> <C-A>
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin
```

Now, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> respectively increase and decrease numbers in Vim.

Mapping to <kbd>Alt</kbd> key combinations is often not evident in Vim; read more about this [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2363/3168).

Answer (score 0):

I am using cygwin terminal + screen, so <c-a> is captured by the terminal multiplexer.   I used this mapping:

:noremap <c-i> <c-a>

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> got mapped somewhere in startup.
As suggested before, use:

unmap <c-x>

I would use unmap, not nunmap.