# Why does < C-a> (CTRL+A) not work under gvim on windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, vim

I'm trying to use the < C-a> (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) shorcut under vim to increment a variable under the cursor. This works fine under vim running on Linux. However when I try to do this in gvim under windows it "selects all" (i.e. highlights or visually selects all text in the current window). How can I change this behaviour or alternatively how can I recover the increment variable functionality (e.g. perhaps with a different key mapping)?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66919/how-to-increment-in-vim-under-windows-where-ctrl-a-does-not-work.I think Paul's answer will be fine

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is because of mswin.vim that is sourced by the default _vimrc generated when you install vim.
Just override your _vimrc with the .vimrc you are using under *nix, or delete mswin.vim.

Comment: mswin.vim is considered evil. I wish Bram would stop including it.

Comment: This can be worked around with mrswin.vim: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=514

Comment: @Zathrus - How can a few lines of text be "evil", do explain.

Comment: @Idigas - I'd provide an example, but I'd probably get banned.

Comment: Why is mswin.vim evil?

Comment: "mswin.vim" is evil, because no one comes from linux- to windows-[g]vim, think about something like that!

Answer (score 8):

I know I'm late to the party, but I thought I'd share the following:

```
nnoremap <kPlus> <C-a>
nnoremap <kMinus> <C-x>
```

This remaps increment to the <kbd>+</kbd> key on the numeric keypad and decrement to the <kbd>-</kbd> key. It's the solution I've used in my own `_vimrc` file on Windows. It keeps the Windows compatibility and is easier to remember than the original <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> as well.

Answer (score 4):

Vim on Windows has specialized key mappings by default to make shortcuts more "windows-y". These are specified in the $VIMRUNTIME\mswin.vim file, which is loaded via your vimrc unless you disabled it. You can edit the mswin.vim file (you may want to edit a copy instead, changing your vimrc to use your edited copy instead).

I'm not entirely sure it's a default Vim mapping, since the only reference I can find on Ctrl+A in the help file is this, which doesn't seem to do what you are referring to:

```
*c_CTRL-A*
CTRL-A      All names that match the pattern in front of the cursor are
              inserted.
```

so you may want to check your Linux box to see if any plugins or anything change the key mapping. (Of course, it may be that I just can't find the appropriate part of the Vim help.)

Comment: ':h CTRL-A' works fine -> http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#CTRL-A

Answer (score 4):

in the current version of mswin.vim provided with gvim, the file checks for the value of a global named `skip_loading_mswin`;  If set, the rest of the file is skipped; thus it is sufficient to add

```
let skip_loading_mswin=1
```

to `$HOME/_vimrc` and normal vim bindings will be restored the next time you start vim.

Answer (score 3):

If you just do not like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> behaviour but are fine with other windows behaviours in VIM (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> for undo), just disable that specific line:

1. Edit said file (`c:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\mswin.vim` for me)
2. Find the paragraph starting with `CTRL-A is Select all`
3. Prepend all (6) lines of that paragraph with opening brackets (`"`)
4. Reopen your GVIM windows.

You can still "select all" by typing `ggVG` (position cursor at first line, select entire line, select until the last line of the document).

Happy incrementing!