# Visual mode in gVim on Windows doesn't work the way as it works in Unix

Tags: windows, vim

I'm using gVim version 7.3 on my Windows. 
When using gVim in my Unix, to insert a common text at the beginning of each line in a file, I do the following steps:

1. Enter visual mode (CTRL+V).
2. Select the lines for which the text has to be inserted at the beginning using arrow keys or hjkl keys.
3. After selection press Shift+I.
4. The cursor goes to the begin of the line where I started. I enter some text and press ESC key.
5. Now the entire block of lines has the text inserted at the beginning.

So here's my question. How do I do the same thing in my gVim on Windows? It's not working if I follow the above as on Unix. Could someone please help me out with this?

Comment: You have to explain at which point of your process you are experiencing a problem. If you don't narrow down the problem/question it's going to be difficult to help you. So… start with the beginning: do you enter visual-block mode with `<C-v>`? If yes, can you move with `<Up>`, `<Down>`, `j`, and/or `k`? If no, what does `<C-v>` do? and so on… consider this problem as a big nested `if/else`, if you want.

Comment: It's quite likely the exact same question as this one (even if the keys that have been detected to behave differently aren't the same) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289681/why-does-c-a-ctrla-not-work-under-gvim-on-windows?rq=1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have `behave mswin` in your vimrc then some of the Vim mappings are modified to be more "Windows-like". In particular you will need to use `<CTRL-Q>` to enter block-visual mode.

I have `behave xterm` in my Windows vimrc which eliminates these issues.

Comment: No problem. Perhaps you could `accept` the answer, if you have no further problems. Thanks.