# Regular expression in vim

Tags: vim

How to replace the strings (4000 to 4200 ) to (5000 to 5200) in vim ..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another possibility:

```
:%s/\v<4([01]\d{2}|200)>/5\1/g
```

This one does 200 as well, and it does not suffer from the "leaning toothpick syndrome" too much since it uses the [\v switch](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic).

EDIT #1: Added word boundary anchors (`'<'` and `'>'`) to prevent replacing `"14100"` etc.

---

EDIT #2: There are cases where a "word boundary" is not enough to correctly capture the wanted pattern. If you want white space to be the delimiting factor, the expression gets somewhat more complex.

```
:%s/\v(^|\s)@<=4([01]\d{2}|200)(\s|$)@=/5\1/g
```

where "`(^|\s)@<=`" is the look-behind assertion for "start-of-line" or "`\s`" and "`(\s|$)@=`" is the look-ahead for "end-of-line" or "`\s`".

Comment: I think that's the cleanest way since it handles the tricky 4200 case implicitly

Answer (score 6):

```
:%s/\<4\([01][0-9][0-9]\)\>/5\1/g
```

Comment: Is there a setting so one can enter

:s/<4(\\[01][0-9][0-9])>/\5\1/g

Answer (score 2):

```
:%s/\<4\([0-1][0-9][0-9]\)\>/5\1/g
```

will do 4000 to 4199. You would have to then do 4200/5200 separately.

A quick explanation. The above finds 4, followed by 0 or 1, followed by 0-9 twice. The 0-1,0-9,0-9 are wrapped in a group, and the replacement (following the slash) says replace with 5 followed by the last matched group  (\1, i.e. the bit following the 4).

\< and > are word boundaries, to prevent matching against 14002 (thx Adrian)

% means across all lines. /g means every match on the line (not just the first one).

Comment: You are missing a `\1`, unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't want to do a full search and replace for some reason, remember that `ctrl-a` will increment the next number below or after the cursor.   So in command mode, you could hit `1000 ctrl-a` to increase the next number by 1000.

If you're on Windows, see an answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66919/how-to-increment-in-vim-under-windows-where-ctrl-a-does-not-work) about how to make `ctrl-a` increment instead of select all.

Answer (score 0):

More typing, but less thinking:

```
:%s/\d\+/\=submatch(0) >= 4000 && submatch(0) <= 4200 ? submatch(0) + 1000 : submatch(0)/g
```