# How to make gvim on Windows behave exactly like linux console vim?

Tags: windows, vim

I have used Vim extensively on linux console, I am used to it's keyboard shortcuts, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for vertical selection, and many others.

I have installed gVim for Windows on my computer at work, and I almost can't use it, as many of keyboard commands were redefined. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> pastes the text from clipboard instead of starting vertical selection for example...

**How make gVim work exactly like the default linux console version,** possibly with the default gentoo settings?

Comment: Once I had a _vimrc in my Documents folder the default _vimrc was not sourced anymore and vim behaved like I wanted it to. Even an empty one was enough.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

in `c:\program files\vim\_vimrc`:

```
" source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
" behave mswin
```

Comment out these two lines

Comment: I just commented out the last two lines (source .../mswin.vim and behave mswin). This seems to break fewer of my other configuration options while still not clobbering the controls.

Answer (score 1):

Issue the following commands:

```
set compatible
:mkvimrc!
```

That will write out a _vimrc that overrules the one in \Program Files\vim

Answer (score 0):

Edit your .vimrc file so that it contains only the line:

```
set compatible
```

Comment: set compatible is not linux standard

Comment: @Nikodemus the question was asking what commands to issue on gvim on Windows. What is or isn't standard in Linux is irrelevant.

Comment: @PaulTomblin: Actually, the question was "How make gVim work exactly like the default linux console version".

Comment: @Nikodemus read it again. "How to make gvim ON WINDOWS work exactly like..."