# How to make gVim on Ubuntu behave like gVim on Windows?

Tags: vim, ubuntu

Searching for an answer I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093578/how-to-make-gvim-on-windows-behave-exacly-like-linux-console-vim), which is an exact opposite case, and the answers gave me a hint - so I went on and entered:

```
:behave mswin
```

This helped with the text selection thing, but I still can't make gVim to move the cursor to the next line once it reached the EOL when using the cursor right key (for example). It just get stuck at the EOL. How can I change this?

**EDIT**:  Just found out that the `<CTRL-A>` for "Select All" does not work as expected as well.

Comment: Check this question out:

http://superuser.com/questions/35389/in-vim-how-do-i-make-the-left-and-right-arrow-keys-change-line

Comment: (Why would you *want* to use the mswin stuff? I used Vim on Windows first and was quite glad to not use it...)

Comment: @ChrisMorgan - well, I used gVim on both systems for quite some time, and probably you can't teach an old dog new tricks - and my habits are more to the Win side. That said. I see gVim as "best in all worlds" so that I actually prefer using gVim instead of some strict Windows style editors (think MS VStudio) for coding, as it really gives me the power of the Unix world. It is just that for some stuff, I find the Win way more convenient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, found the missing piece - once sourcing

```
:source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
```

the behavior did change as expected.